# can resolve or anything be used inside the views section of state in $stateprovider in ui-router to pass a specific data to controller of angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a requirement to get a specific data into the controller which is present inside views section of the state of the $stateProvider of ui-router

```
state('main', {
      abstract: true
      url: "/main"
      controller: 'MainController'
      templateUrl: "main.html"
    })
.state('main.state1', {
  url: "",
  views: {
    'view1': {
      resolve: function() {
        return {
          configuration: "widget1"
        };
      },
      templateUrl: "sample1.html",
      controller: 'Controller1'
    },
    'view2': {
      resolve: function() {
        return {
          configuration: "widget2"
        };
      },
      templateUrl: "sample2.html",
      controller: 'Controller2'
    },
    'view3': {
      resolve: function() {
        return {
          configuration: "widget3"
        };
      },
      templateUrl: "sample3.html",
      controller: 'Controller3'
    },
    'view4': {
      resolve: function() {
        return {
          configuration: "widget4"
        };
      },
      templateUrl: "sampl4.html",
      controller: 'Controller4'
    }
  }
});
```

Now my question will this code work for give the following result

1. controller1 in the above gets the value of configuration as widget1
2. controller2 in the above gets the value of configuration as widget2
3. controller3 in the above gets the value of configuration as widget3
4. controller4 in the above gets the value of configuration as widget4

***if this is not possible then How can I pass the value to the individual controllers***

My main.html file looks like this

```
<div class="main-column">
  <div class="detail-container">
    <h2>{{pageTitle | translate}}</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="grid grid-flex">
    <div autoscroll="false"  ui-view="view1"></div>
    <div autoscroll="false"  ui-view="view2"></div>
    <div autoscroll="false"  ui-view="view3"></div>
    <div autoscroll="false"  ui-view="view4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to pass a data, dont need a resolve then do like this

```
.state('state1', {
    url: 'url',
    templateUrl: 'views/misc/profile.html',
    controller: 'profileController',
    data: {
       configuration: 'widget'
    }
 });
```

If you need resolve then try this.

```
state('state1', {
  url: "url.html",
  views: {
    'view1': {
      resolve: {
        configuration: function() {
            return "widget1";
        }
      },
      templateUrl: "sample1.html",
      controller: 'Controller1'
    },
    'view2': {
      resolve: {
        configuration: function() {
            return "widget2";
        }
      },
      templateUrl: "sample2.html",
      controller: 'Controller2'
    },
    'view3': {
      resolve: {
        configuration: function() {
            return "widget3";
        }
      },
      templateUrl: "sample3.html",
      controller: 'Controller3'
    },
    'view4': {
      resolve: {
        configuration: function() {
            return "widget4";
        }
      },
      templateUrl: "sampl4.html",
      controller: 'Controller4'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I was am not sure if resolve can work at the views level. I thought it was at the state level. we tried with data initially but it looks like it didn't work. anyways thanks a lot I will give a try

Comment: data was not working at the views level. This is a case of multiple views on same html file. I was looking to pass a different values to different controllers in the same state under views section

Comment: I have updated the question to make question more clear

Comment: The resolve keyword MUST be relative to state not views (in case you use multiple views).
The resolve keys MUST be injected into the child states if you want to wait for the promises to be resolved before instantiating the children.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. One more small query you have used $scope.xx = $state.current.views.viewA.data in the controller to get the data. Is it some how possible to get the value of data without knowing the "viewA"  I mean because we are writing a generic controller and some how the controller should know which view they are in and get the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80790/discussion-between-none-and-simon).